# why doesnt this print command result in key being printed twice?

Tags: python

im just doing an exercise on codecademy and im confused as to why the print command isnt just printing the key twice?

```
    my_dict = {
"a" : "alpha",
"b" : "bravo",
"c" : "charlie"
}



    for key in my_dict:
      print key, " ", my_dict[key]
```

it outputs this, which is correct, as the aim is to print the key and the value..

```
    a   alpha
    c   charlie
    b   bravo
```

but i dont understand why my_dict[key] prints the value and not the key, considering it says key.
any explanation would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: But you are not printing the key. You are printing the result of the `my_dict[key]` expression. That expression returns the value for the key.

Comment: Do you know what the `mydict[]` part means?

Comment: Analogy: Why is "Steve's dad" not Steve? It says "Steve", after all.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behavior of a dictionary as explained in the Python docs. Try to think of it as a "index" of sorts. So when you call my_dict[key], you are asking for the value of the key(or "index") that you are calling. If you wish to print the key, you would just need to call the key directly as you did in the beginning of the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a list.  To get the first value in the list we would

```
print list_name[0]
```

The `0` identifies the element in the list.  Lists hold values that are accessed by an integer index.  With a dictionary we don't use an integer index, but some other object to identify the position.  That other object is often a string as in your example.  The process of converting the object into a position is done using a *hash algorithm* which you really don't want to know about, other than it works.

So, in:

```
my_dict = {
    "a" : "alpha",
    "b" : "bravo",
    "c" : "charlie"
}
```

we have three values, "alpha", 'bravo", "charlie".  Their position in memory is determined by using the keys "a", "b', or "c".  So `my_dict["b"]` enables Python to calculate the position of the value "bravo" and retrieve it.

Your loop just gets each key in turn and retrieves the values.  When you print `key` you get the key, when you print `my_dict[key]` the python sees the `[ ]` and calls special code to invoke the hash algorithm and retrieve the value.

By the way, if you try `my_dict[value]` that would not work.  The retrieval can only work from key to value.  There are several reasons for this, but one is that keys in a dictionary are unique, whereas values need not be.  Another is that values can change, but a key cannot simply because the hash algorithm would give a different result.